# Localize jitsi_meet_flutter

Tags: flutter, jitsi-meet

Trying to connect to my jitsi server from my mobile flutter app using jitsi_meet_flutter plugin which calls the server like this

```
.invokeMethod<String>('joinMeeting', <String, dynamic>{
          'room': options.room?.trim(),
          'serverURL': options.serverURL?.trim(),
          'subject': options.subject,
          'token': options.token,
          'audioMuted': options.audioMuted,
          'audioOnly': options.audioOnly,
          'videoMuted': options.videoMuted,
          'userDisplayName': options.userDisplayName,
          'userEmail': options.userEmail,
          'config.defaultLanguage':"ptBR"
        }
```

The last line 'config.defaultLanguage':"ptBR" was added by me in the hope that would load the ptBR version, but it didn’t (does not throw error either). On the server I already changed the config so it loads ptBR when connecting thru a desktop browser. That works but I needed the mobile client to also show the user interface in porutguese. Help appreciated.

Comment: I am confused. You talk about the above code sending the Localization language code to the server from the Flutter app. Is that call to the server being picked up OK? Have you built any Localization handling into the Flutter app?

Comment: In order to understand the question you must be familiar with both jitsi server and the jitsi_meet_flutter plugin

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck.